# wicket models is not updated

Tags: java, hyperlink, wicket

I have a Link in the constructor of the class `DetailsPanel` and I want it to save a change in the form of the class DetailsPanel when I click on it and go to the next page.

When I use for example `if(propertyModel.getSomething() != null) { // change something }` in the constructor `Details()` the change is made.

When I do the same in the constructor `DetailsPanel()` that is `if(info.getSomething() != null) { // change something }` the change is not made because the model is not updated when I click the link. It just goes to the next page and when I go back the change does not remain..

I have tested the code and the value of "something" passes in both cases.

I am just trying to understand how the wicket model works here...

```
public class DetailsPanel extends Panel {

    private static final class Details extends BootstrapForm<InfoModel> {

        public Details(String id, final CompoundPropertyModel<InfoModel> propertyModel) { 
            // form with various components..  
        }
    }

    public DetailsPanel(String id, final InfoModel info) {
        // my link is here
    }
}

public class InfoModel implements IClusterable {
    // private fields with getters and setters eg.
    private int something;
}
```

Comment: What type of link are you using?

Comment: The simplest type  final Link myLink = new Link("myLink") {
            
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            
            @Override
            public void onClick() {   }};

Comment: A link does not sumbit a form. Try using a button to submit it.

Comment: I have already a button that submits the form but I have to modify the link (of a stepper) to do the same when the user changes something.. My only problem is that I cant save the change that is to update the wicket model.. I have tried all the types of Wicket Links but none seems to work for me..